# Create checkbox from map in Thymeleaf. SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try create list of checkbox from Map but I get error.  Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userConfig", new UserConfig());
    return "home";
}
```

My class UserConfig

```
@Component public class UserConfig {

private Map<String, Boolean> isEnableMap = new HashMap<>();

public UserConfig(){
    isEnableMap.put(EnableProcess.MONTHLY_TIME_UPDATE.getTitle(), true);
    isEnableMap.put(EnableProcess.SUM.getTitle(), true);
    isEnableMap.put(EnableProcess.HIDE_COLUMNS.getTitle(), true);
}

public UserConfig(Map<String, Boolean> isEnableMap) {
    this.isEnableMap = isEnableMap;
}

public Map<String, Boolean> getIsEnableMap() {
    return isEnableMap;
}

public void setIsEnableMap(Map<String, Boolean> isEnableMap) {
    this.isEnableMap = isEnableMap;
}
```

This is my home.html snippet

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" th:action="@{/file/uploadFile}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"
        />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn-form" id="file" name="file" type="file" required/>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
            <p>
            <!--/*@thymesVar id="monthlyTimeUpdate" 

type="mypacked.service.UserConfig"*/-->
<!--                <input type="checkbox" th:field="${userConfig.monthlyTimeUpdate}"/> Update monthly time</p>-->
            <!--/*@thymesVar id="errorMessageNoFound" type=""*/-->
            <span th:if="${errorMessageNoFound}" th:text="${errorMessageNoFound}"/>
            <p th:each="item : ${userConfig.isEnableMap}">
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{item.key}" th:value="${item.value}"/>
            </p>
        </div>

        </form>
```

Line 37

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{item.key}" th:value="${item.value}"/>
                </p>
```

> > ERROR 20457 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template
> > "home": Error during execution of processor
> > 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor'
> > (template: "home" - line 37, col 40)
>
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during
> execution of processor
> 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor'
> (template: "home" - line 37, col 40)  at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.StandaloneElementTag.beHandled(StandaloneElementTag.java:228)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.CloseElementTag.beHandled(CloseElementTag.java:139)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:661)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na] Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
> target object for bean name 'item' available as request attribute     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:153)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
> ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]    at
> org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
> ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]

it works but chexbox no :

```
              <p th:each="item : ${userConfig.isEnableMap}">
            <span th:text="*{item.key}"></span>
            <span th:text="*{item.value}"></span>
```